# What's the relation between the type (Gender) of a balloon and its internal pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, elasticity

I'm working on a project about balloons and I need to know the relation between the gender of the balloon and its internal pressure. As far as I know, there are some parameters such as " Elasticity of the Balloons " or other things that will directly or indirectly effect on the internal pressure (P) of the balloon. I want you to denote these relations by formulas if it's possible.

Comment: What do you mean by the "gender" of a balloon? I'm not familiar with that expression. Could you give some examples of different types of balloons you are interested in?

Comment: For example, one balloons's elasticity is difference or one balloon's thickness is difference.